# how to pass input value via jquery to php in magento adminhtml

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, magento

In Catalog > Attribute > manage atrribute > Manage label/ options. I have created a module that will pull/display 
options of selected category. i have done all the code that will do the work.

Now the problem is here:

i want to pass a value of selected option (category id) from html list.

This is how I pull and display the list of my categories.

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Attribute/Edit/Tab/Options.php

 public function getCategoryCollection(){
        $parentCategoryName = 'Default Category';
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
            ->addFieldToFilter('name', $parentCategoryName)
            ->getFirstItem()// The parent category
            ->getChildrenCategories();


        $html = "<select>";
        $html = $html. "<option>Select</option>";
        foreach ($collection as $items => $item) {
            $html = $html . "<option value=" . $item->getEntityId() . ">" . $item->getName() . "</option>";
        }

        $html = $html . "</select>";

        return $html;
    }
```

this is the function I want to pass when user do "onchange()" on the html select list

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Attribute/Edit/Tab/Options.php

public function getCategoryOptions(){

        // Id of category we want to get attributes for
        $categoryId = 123;
        $sizeOption = array();
        // Products in that category
        $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId); //put your category id here
        $productslist = $products->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        foreach($productslist as $product)
        {
            $sizeOption[] = $product['attribute_variant'];
        }
        return $sizeOption;
    }
```

app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/eav/attribute/options.phtml
I use "`<td><?php echo $this->getCategoryCollection(); ?></td>`" to display the select options list. 
Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: You will have to use a parameter in the `getCategoryOptions()`and set `$categoryId = $mParameter`. How can you get the current category ID?

Comment: At the moment I am manually passing the value on $categoryId. i'm looking for a way to do this via html select option.

Comment: does the `$item` in the `foreach($collections)` contains a category id? or is it `$item->getEntityId()`?

Comment: Yes it does have the category id in it

Comment: Where is the `getCategoryOptions()` being called?

Comment: i use it in app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/eav/attribute/options.phtml. the select input get displayed correctly with in  <td><?php echo $this->getCategoryCollection(); ?></td>

Comment: Can you share the code? (i need `getCategoryOptions()` not `getCategoryCollection()`)

Comment: you mean the phtml code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138724/discussion-between-antonis-tsimourtos-and-mthe-beseti).